# Where to find symbols used in font?

Tags: android, fonts, roboto

So I'm working on a project where we use a symbol in our text and I'd like to extract it in high quality (or in vector graphic) from the font or wherever it resides... The problem is the pencil looks different depending on where it shows up. Currently I need it from Android, so the best approach I've found is to take a high density tablet and make a view displaying ONLY that symbol. Please teach me about how this work and where it resides as I can't seem to figure it out myself.

In my case the symbol I need is the LOWER RIGHT PENCIL: ✎. [Here you can see more info about it in different encodings](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/270e/index.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as explained the best approach was to simply take a high density screen shot from Android where the correct font was used.